# C# Process as administrator

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-7

I'm trying to run powershell script, but during this operation is required administrator rights for powershell.exe.
Using this example everything working successfully

```
        var process = new Process();
        const string password = "pwd";
        SecureString str;

        char[] chArray = password.ToCharArray();

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (char* chRef = chArray)
            {
                str = new SecureString(chRef, chArray.Length);
            }
        }

        var info = new ProcessStartInfo
                                    {
                                        FileName = "powershell.exe",
                                        //UserName = username,
                                        //Password = str,
                                        //Domain = domain,

                                        UseShellExecute = true,
                                        Verb = "runas",
                                        Arguments = arguments

                                    };
        process.StartInfo = info;

        process.Start();
```

but it calls User Account Controll and I should press "OK".

if I comment verb and set shellexecute as false PS console starting with non-administrator rights.

How can I avoid UAC to run powershell.exe with administrator rights?

Comment: If that was possible, malicious code could do it as well. You need to lower the security

Comment: UAc is there for a reason :)

Comment: You could try these methods: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/stop-annoying-uac-prompts-how-to-create-a-user-account-control-whitelist-windows/

Comment: @Moo-Juice Yeah, to irritate developers ;)

Comment: Is the C# app running as a user, or administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable UAC, you can google for instructions. End users of your app will have to deal, but you can ensure your app has admin rights off the jump by altering the [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).